# How to escape properly and output regex in latex?

Tags: verbatim, text-manipulation

Escaping regex is a heck of a work on LaTeX. How should I write in latex syntax such that I can output the following regexes:

```
^\(?\s?\w{1,5}\s*[):.]\s*
```

and

```
[\[\(].{1,}[\]\)]
```

I've tried `\text{[\[\(].{1,}[\]\)]}` but it gives compilation errors.

Comment: Did you try just `\verb|^\(?\s?\w{1,5}\s*[):.]\s*|`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *verbatim* (fancyvrb package) or *listings*  environnement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
    ^(?\s?\w{1,5}\s*[):.]\s*
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might include also a description of the standard `\verb` command and of `\Verb` (from `fancyvrb`)

Comment: The _Verbatim_ from fancyvrb is just more sophisticated than the standard _verbatim_. From the official documentation, it says that it offers six kinds of extended functionality, as I am not understanding the whole particularities, I remember mainly: several verbatim commands enhanced and you can use it in footnotes.  After this, I am referring to the documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf

Comment: @gapz However, I wouldn't want to write `\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]...\end{Verbatim}` every time, especially since it's not necessary and `\verb§...§` does the same job.

Comment: That's right (actually, I wanted to produce an example with a frame for the visualization, but you're right to point it, "we" have to be as precise and concise as possible).